# how to create a trigger that calculates the sum of one field with matching id from one table to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need write a trigger that calculates the sum of bills for each *dinerId* in the Visits table and updates that value to the *totalBill* in the Diners table.

The Diners table can be updated every time there's a new record inserted to the Visits table.
If a record is deleted from the Visits table, it makes sense the the *totalBill* value in the Diners table will be updated.

If any other fields (other from '*bills*') are being updated in the Visits table, than nothing should change, otherwise it should be updated accordingly.

There are 2 more tables but there's not need to mention them.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--creating tables
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--creating table Diners
CREATE TABLE Diners( 
dinerId            NUMBER(2),
name               VARCHAR2(1),
Phone              NUMBER(2),
totalBill          NUMBER(4),
City               VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT dinerId_pk PRIMARY KEY   (dinerId)
);

--
-- other tables . . .
--

--creating table Visits
CREATE TABLE Visits( 
dinerId             NUMBER(2), 
visitDay            VARCHAR2(3),
tnum                NUMBER(2), 
Wid                 NUMBER(3), 
numOfDiners         NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
Bill                NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 0,

CONSTRAINT visit_pk PRIMARY KEY     (dinerId,visitDay),
CONSTRAINT  dinerId_fk FOREIGN KEY  (dinerId) REFERENCES Diners(dinerId),
CONSTRAINT tnum_fk FOREIGN KEY      (tnum) REFERENCES Tables(tnum),
CONSTRAINT  wid_fk FOREIGN KEY      (Wid) REFERENCES Waiters(Wid),
CONSTRAINT visitdays check((visitDay IN ('SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI')))
);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--inserting data to tables
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--inserting data to Diners
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (1,'A', 11,null,'AA');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (2,'B', 33,null, 'CC');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (3,'C', 66,null, 'CC');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (4,'C', 55,null, 'DD');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (5,'D', 44,null,'CC');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (6,'A', 22,null, 'BB');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (7,'B', 22,null, 'BB');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (8,'D', 33,null, 'CC');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (9,'E', 11,null, 'AA');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (10,'F', 77,null, 'DD');
INSERT INTO Diners  VALUES (11,'F', 22,null, 'BB');

---------------tools for diners----------------------
--desc diners;
--drop table diners;
--SELECT * from diners;
-----------------------------------------------------

--inserting data to Visits
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (1,'SUN', 5, 222, 2,400);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (5,'SUN', 5, 222, 1,200);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (6,'SUN', 7, 111, 3,500);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (3,'MON', 9, 333, 5,325);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (10,'MON', 9, 444, 6,801);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (5,'MON', 3, 111, 1,400);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (5,'TUE', 3, 111, 1,128);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (7,'FRI', 7, 111, 4,551);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (2,'FRI', 6, 444, 5,630);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (3,'FRI', 2, 444, 3,225);
INSERT INTO Visits  VALUES (4,'TUE', 3, 333,2,238);

-------------tools for Visits------------------------
--desc Visits;
--drop table Visits;
--SELECT * from visits;
-----------------------------------------------------



------------- creating trigger ----------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER  calc_customer_totalBills
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF  Bill
    ON Visits
    FOR EACH ROW
    --  ?? --
```

here are my necessary tables :
[image: the Diners tables, where the totalBill need to be updated :]

[image: the Visits tables, for which the bills of each diner need to be summed]

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax so I removed the tag.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Have you tried something? You are asking us to create the entire trigger code. Try to learn trigger, create code by yourself and ask the question if you get stuck.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Normally, using triggers to store easily computed aggregate values like this is a poor design decision.  If this is a homework assignment, have you tried anything?  We're happy to help but it's hard to provide good pointers if we don't know where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a proper way to hold such a column (`totalbill`) and create a trigger to populate it continuously, considering a good database design. Since, it's(`totalbill`) might already be computed by using existing columns (`dinerid` and `bill`). Perhaps, a future corruption may occur for the values of `totalbill` with a wrong update statement for the current case. Rather prefer removing `totalbill` column from the table, and create a view which computes the summed up value for each `dinerid` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_Diners_Total AS
SELECT d.dinerid, SUM(v.bill) AS totalbill  
  FROM Diners d
  LEFT JOIN Visits v
    ON v.dinerid = d.dinerid
 GROUP BY d.dinerid   
 ORDER BY d.dinerid
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=299884d33daae0850e8f4413674c9ec7)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_visits
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON visits
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      UPDATE Diners
         SET totalBill = COALESCE( totalBill, 0) + :NEW.Bill
       WHERE dinerId = :NEW.dinerId;
   ELSIF DELETING
   THEN
      UPDATE Diners
         SET totalBill = COALESCE( totalBill, 0) - :OLD.Bill
       WHERE dinerId = :OLD.dinerId;
   END IF;
END;
/
```